# UITableViewStyleGrouped moveItemAtIndexPath does not update separators iOS7

Tags: uitableview, ios7

It seems that grouped separators do not redraw after doing a moveItemAtIndexPath animation.

See to left of image, I moved cell1 row index 0 to index 2.  Cell 2 and Cell 1 separators are incorrect.

[image]

Any way around this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a way around it, but not that pretty as the separators are redrawn suddenly after the move animation.  But at least they are valid after the move, and the move animation is kept.  Basically, reload after we detect the move animation is completed:

```
    [CATransaction begin];

    [CATransaction setCompletionBlock: ^{
             [self.tableView reloadData];
    }];


    [self.tableView beginUpdates];

    [self.tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:fromIndexPath toIndexPath:toIndexPath];

    [self.tableView endUpdates];

    [CATransaction commit];
```